Склоняется ли часть после двоеточия?
Имеется следующее предложение: Продолжение следует в «Эпизоде втором: появление соперника!». Будет ли слово появление склоняться так же, как и эпизод? То есть что нужно выбрать: Продолжение следует в «Эпизоде втором: появление соперника!» или Продолжение следует в «Эпизоде втором: появлении соперника!»?

Правильно:
Продолжение следует в «Эпизоде втором: появление соперника!»
Пояснение

Рассмотрим вариант:

Продолжение следует в эпизоде втором "появление соперника!".
Здесь  приложение относится названию эпизода "появление соперника", которое не склоняется. Сравнить: в романе Пушкина "Евгений Онегин".

При другой записи грамматика остается та же, то есть вторая часть имени собственного не склоняется.

